# ¿como crear un contador o sumador con php?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, jquery, ajax

Necesito alguna sugerencia de como realizar un contador o sumador de **kilometraje**: de una tabla de mi base de datos llamada `carga_combustible` tomo el campo `km_final` y le aplico un `SUM` para realizar una suma del **kilometraje** de ese vehículo es decir el vehículo con el nombre `tsuru` lleva acumulado un total de **10000 km** como se muestra en la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al llegar a los **10000 km** o sobrepasarlos el sistema debe arrojar una alerta que indique que ese vehículo ya llego a los **10000 km** o que ya los paso, y sino arroja una alerta de que aun no llega a los **10000 km**, eso lo realizo de la siguiente manera,"este código funciona":

```
<?php
$vehiculo=$_POST['vehiculo'];
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","controldeflotilla") or die (mysqli_error());

$query="SELECT  SUM(km_final) AS totalkilometros, vehiculo FROM carga_combustible WHERE vehiculo ='$vehiculo'";
$result=mysqli_query($con, $query) or die (mysqli_error());

$total=0;
 while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
 $totalkm=$total+$row[0];
 $auto=$row['vehiculo'];
}

if ($totalkm>=10000){
echo "<div class='container'style='width:500px'>
<table class='table table-hover table-sm table-bordered table-condensed'>
<thead class='thead-dark text-center'>
<tr>
<th>Vehículo</th>
<th>Kilometraje</th>
<th>Prioridad</th>
<th>Mantenimiento</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody class='text-center'>
<tr>
<td>$auto</td>
<td>$totalkm</td>
<td>Alta<img src='img/alerta_alta.png' style='width:40px'></td>
<td><a href='reg_mantenimiento.php' class='btn btn-danger'><img src='img/mtto1.png' style='width:25px'></a>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>";
}
else{
echo "<div class='container'style='width:500px'>
<table class='table table-hover table-sm table-bordered table-condensed'>
<thead class='thead-dark text-center'>
<tr>
<th>Vehículo</th>
<th>Kilometraje</th>
<th>Prioridad</th>
<th>Mantenimiento</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody class='text-center'>
<tr>
<td>$auto</td>
<td>$totalkm</td>
<td>Baja<img src='img/alerta_baja.png' style='width:40px'></td>
<td><a href='reg_mantenimiento.php' class='btn btn-info'><img src='img/mtto1.png' style='width:25px'>
</a><p style='font-size:12px'>¡Aun no requerido!</p>

</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>";

 }
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Para consultar si el vehículo llego a dicho **kilometraje** el usuario debe seleccionar el vehículo y dar clic al botón enviar, de esta manera aparece una pequeña tabla de manera de alerta con la información del vehículo y su **kilometraje** actual ya sumado de esta manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Todo funciona bien cuando el **kilometraje** del vehículo comienza en 0 hasta que llegue a los **10000 km** me va arrojar la alerta correctamente, pero como sabemos un vehículo va a sobrepasar los **10000 km** y va seguir aumentado su **kilometraje** , entonces mi código y mi alerta siempre va mandar que ya sobrepaso los **10000 km** cuando el vehículo lo haga, el problema es que no encuentro como resolver el ir aumentando cada **10000** km mi condición `if` para que cada que mi vehículo acumule **10000 km** me tire la alerta, supongamos ya llego a los **10000 km** se reinicia mi contador y cuando llegue a los **20000 km** me tire la alerta por que ya volvió a acumular otros **10000 km**

Comment: No sé, se me ocurrió algo pues no sé que tan bueno pueda ser, puedes hacer que en la condición `if ($totalkm>=10000){` o a parte, no tengo una idea ahora muy bien, que sí supera los 10000, que se le reste 10000 a esa variable y se guarde en otra, y si sigue superando los 10000 que los reste otra vez y se agregue en la otra variable, entonces que en la otra variable se guarde cuanto fue el kilometraje que se superó, más o menos tengo la idea así

Comment: con un while es mejor, sí te gusta la idea, avisame para ver sí te la planteo mejor en la respuesta

Comment: pues estoy abierto a cualquier propuesta, es que tengo ideas pero no se como enfocarlas a lo que estoy realizando, te cuento estoy creando alertas de mantenimiento de vehículos por lo cual cada que un vehículo acumule 10000 km le corresponde un mantenimiento, pero no se como realizar las condiciones para cuando sobrepase los 10000 km y acumule 20,30,40 mil y así sucesivamente, lo mas fácil seria poner muchos if con cada una de las opciones  if>=20000 , if>= 30000, etc ... pero queria un sumador o contador que lo hiciera en automático

Comment: Pues mira, ya te planteo una forma de hacer el contador como te lo estaba diciendo, ya que digamos que sí excedió 20000, pues digamos que tiene 21000, pero con otra que guardara esos 20000 que es el kilometraje que excedió, entonces con esa variable harías un mensaje o la alerta, `"Se excedieron los ". $excedido. " tienes que realizar mantenimiento ";` ya te muestro para que te haga una mejor idea

Comment: Listo, mira a ver sí algo así es lo que quieres

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como ya te había comentado, podrías hacer un `while` que te vaya diciendo el valor que se excedió se pueda guardar en una variable a parte y que te diga sí se sobrepasó los 20000 o 30000, etc. Entonces se puede hacer de esta manera

Código `PHP`

```
<?php
    $excedido = 0;
    while($totalkm>= 10000){
      $excedido += 10000;
      $totalkm-= 10000;
    }
    echo "se excedió ". $excedido;
?>
```

o si quieres es saber cual es el próximo kilometraje que va a exceder, podría ser así

```
<?php
    $excedido = 0;
    $mensaje;
    while($totalkm >= 10000){
      $excedido += 10000;
      $totalkm-= 10000;
    }
    $mensaje = "se excedió ". $excedido;
    if($totalkm >= 5000 && $totalkm < 10000){
        $excedido += 10000;
        $mensaje = "alerta de proximo kilometraje " . $excedido;
    }
    echo $mensaje;
?>
```

[Prueba el primero](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1101fecc5e73d057375ee20c64c895f71e53674e)

[Prueba el segundo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/89e57e5f2583b64dd6c3e38d3575b925aa86a872)

Espero que te sea de ayuda, saludos!!

Comment: como puede meter el while que me indicas dentro del while que ya tengo es que el while que ya tengo me ayuda a obtener en la variable $totalkm lo que me retorno la consulta:

Comment: $query="SELECT  SUM(km_final) AS totalkilometros, vehiculo FROM carga_combustible WHERE vehiculo ='$vehiculo'";
$result=mysqli_query($con, $query) or die (mysqli_error());

 $total=0;
 while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
 $totalkm=$total+$row[0];
 $auto=$row['vehiculo'];
}

Comment: No necesariamente debes ponerlo adentro, puedes colocarlo después, ya que dentro de ese while que me dices estás recogiendo los datos de la consulta

Comment: ok ya funciono pero tus opciones me sirven para hacer dos cosas por ejemplo la primera opción me sirve para mandar un mensaje de los que ya llegaron o se pasaron de los 10,20,30,40,50 mil km y la segunda para mandar un mensaje de los que están próximos , pero como podría poner ambas opciones en un if o en switch para si no se cumple una se cumpla la otra y asi obtener ambos mensajes de alerta

Comment: Puedes poner una variable mensaje para cuando pase una cosa o la otra, por ejemplo, sí él no entra al `if` que puse después del `while` entonces él no dice los proximos, entonces dentro del `if` se puede meter un mensaje distinto, ya lo edito para que te hagas idea

Comment: Listo, miralo a ver sí es lo que quieres

Comment: excelente era justo lo que necesitaba muchas gracias por tu tiempo y tu apoyo, ya funciono como queria

Comment: Me alegra, fue un placer haber ayudado, suerte con tu proyecto, saludos!